# Large Panorama to Panning Video

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

What would be the most efficient way to create a video from a panoramic image that would for example have the size: `5000 width x 600 height` px?

I created this GIF image that would explain things a bit better. Imagine that the video would be inside the red border. So the video would potentially be panning from left to right.

[image: GIF explanation]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A moving crop is the most convenient way to achieve this in ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i in.jpg -vf "crop=500:ih:'min((iw/10)*t,9*iw/10)':0" -t 10 pan.mp4
```

The crop filter crops to a size of 500 x ih i.e. 500x600. The top-left co-ordinate of the cropping window is fixed to Y=0. For X, the expression is `min((iw/10)*t,9*iw/10)` i.e. in each second, the cropping window will slide across 10% of the image width. So, at t=9, the cropping window covers (4500,0) to (5000,600) for the example image. From that time, the min function returns the other value `9*iw/10` = `4500` and the sliding stops.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it outputs this: `No such filter: '9*iw/10):0'` but could be that I missed a syntax or something. Got any suggestions? @Mulvya

Comment: Enclose the whole vf argument in double-quotes.

Comment: Works! Thank you

Comment: Same error happens if you forget to add the single quotes for the ih, mostly because i was editing an older command and had the double quotes but forgot to add single quotes so the function works

Comment: How would you do this in the opposite direction, right to left?

Comment: The expr for x will become `max((9-t)*iw/10,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically Crop a panorama video to 1280x720 with timestamp settings from a detector:

```
ffmpeg script: crop=1280:ih:'func_cropstartx':0
func_cropstartx:
cropstartx[0] = location[0].x
for every location 0 < i <= N:
    cropstartx[i] = if (gte(t\, location[i].time)\, location[i].x\, cropstartx[i-1]);
```

Use a sorted list of setpoints
Example:

```
crop = 1280:ih:'if(gte(t\,10)\,600\,if(gte(t\,8)\,400\,if(gte(t\,6)\,300\,if(gte(t\,4)\,200\,100))))' : 0
```